# Taking unexpectedly long amount of time to transform message in kstreams application

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have a pretty basic use case kstreams application where I am debouncing messages for a few seconds and then using transform to either remove or store the message in a state store.  I also have a punctuate method that fires every 30 seconds to go through the store and emit the messages.

What I'm finding is that from the time my application gets the message to the time it makes it to the transform function takes much longer than I would expect(I would assume the transform function happens pretty quickly after the window expires).  This is not entirely an issue for my use case but I am curious as to what might be taking so long to make it to the transform function.

```
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Payload>> store = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(keyValueStoreName),
            Serdes.String(),
            avroSerde
    );
    builder.addStateStore(store);

    final Consumed<String, Payload> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde)
            .withTimestampExtractor(new WallclockTimestampExtractor());
    final Produced<String, Payload> produced = Produced.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde);
    final KStream<String, Payload> stream = builder.stream(inputTopic, consumed);
    final SessionWindows sessionWindows = SessionWindows
            .with(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    final SessionWindowTransformerSupplier transformerSupplier =
            new SessionWindowTransformerSupplier(keyValueStoreName, scheduleTimeSeconds);
    final SessionBytesStoreSupplier sessionBytesStoreSupplier = Stores.persistentSessionStore(
            "debounce-window",
            Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    final Materialized<String, Payload, SessionStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materializedAs =
            Materialized.as(sessionBytesStoreSupplier);

    stream
            .selectKey((key, value) -> {
                logger.info("selecting key: " + key);
                return key;
            })
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(sessionWindows)
            .reduce(payloadDebounceFunction::apply, materializedAs)
            .toStream()
            .transform(transformerSupplier, keyValueStoreName)
            .to(outputTopic, produced);

    return builder;
```

Here is my transform/punctuate method:

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.processorContext = context;
    this.store = (KeyValueStore<String, Payload>) context.getStateStore(keyValueStoreName);
    context.schedule(ofSeconds(scheduleTime), WALL_CLOCK_TIME, timestamp -> punctuate());
}

@Override
public KeyValue<String, Payload> transform(Windowed<String> key, Payload value) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if(value != null) {
            BatchScanStatus status = extractStatus(value);
            boolean removeFromStoreStatus = BatchScanStatus.CANCELLED.equals(status)
                    || BatchScanStatus.FINALIZING.equals(status);

            if(removeFromStoreStatus) {
                logger.info("Deleting key from store: {}", key);
                store.delete(key.key());
            } else {
                logger.info("Adding key to store: {}", key);
                store.putIfAbsent(key.key(), value);
            }
            processorContext.commit();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void punctuate() {
    synchronized (this) {
        final KeyValueIterator<String, Payload> keyIter = store.all();
        while(keyIter.hasNext()) {
            final KeyValue<String, Payload> record = keyIter.next();
            logger.info("Forwarding key: {}", record.key);
            processorContext.forward(record.key, record.value);
        }

        keyIter.close();
    }
}
```

The length of time it takes to get from the selectKey function to the transform function confuses me as in this run it took ~24 seconds

```
15:58:35.238 [scheduler-79112bd0-2310-482e-9aab-8bcaae746082-StreamThread-1] INFO  c.b.d.f.s.kstreams.Scheduler - selecting key: keykeykey
15:58:59.181 [scheduler-79112bd0-2310-482e-9aab-8bcaae746082-StreamThread-1] INFO  c.b.d.f.s.k.s.SessionTransformer - Adding key to store: [keykeykey@1570737515238/1570737515238]
```

Does kstreams do more work than it appears here in order for something like this to take the amount of time that it does?  Hoping to get some enlightenment on whether this is a configuration/timing issue or if this is normal behavior for a kstreams application.

EDIT: I think I have found where I have gone wrong and it has to do with the default value of commit.interval.ms.

Changes were not getting committed to the internal topic until it checked and thus, my transform function would not fire until these changes arrived on the internal topic.  I shortened this to a second and immediately saw the difference.